# Can I create a whirlpool/vortex around a horizontal axis in a flat bottle using motor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics, torque

I am using this flat bottle:

I fixed a motor at the centre of one of the flat sides and attached an impeller. I thought this will create some kind of whirlpool effect but as you can guess, since the motor is horizontal, the water also rotated about a horizontal axis. But it did not create any much effects. I turned up the power but I was afraid my motor could not get any faster.

My question is: do you think if I install a more powerful and faster motor, it will eventually create a mini vortex/whirlpool? If you saw the picture, the width of bottle is only around 2cm so its not very taxing I think?

What I am originally trying to do is to create some kind of continuous cool effect in the bottle. I initially planned to do something like [this lava lamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCuFjXGSVB4&ab_channel=CreativeSL) by using pump to continuously circulate water in oil instead of the alka seltzer but it ended up mixing the oil and water into a cloudy solution. Another option was to create bubbles but I don't like that as its very generic.

So is it possible to create horizontal whirlpool/vortex? Or is there any other cool effects you can suggest I can make?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a video and images of what you did, and describe in more detail what you hope to achieve?

Comment: I have edited the question now with actual photo.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very short answer on a very wide and interesting subject.

Try different impellers, (look for **vortex impellers** on google) e.g.:

[image]

or

[image]

**Different designs** would require different **power** to achieve a similar effect depending on **viscosity** and **density** of the liquid.

Comment: So a horizontal vortex can be created? Is it a possibility if I use a suitable impeller?

Comment: I am not sure what would you qualify as vortex (i.e. separation from the walls). It should be possible in a larger setup. In the confines of those plastic bottles, I am a bit skeptical to be honest, although I don't have much experience in agitators and those types of processes.

Comment: Horizontal, vertical only matter because of gravity so in theory if you can overpower gravity significantly, it won't matter.  The issue with your bottle is getting the flow you seek.  You would have to circulate air all the way from the top to your impeller for the visual effect you want.  More air, less liquid might help, or putting the water-oil divide closer to the motor maybe with one of these impellera

Answer (score 0):

I try to translate what you want to achieve into engineering terminology:

- you want to create a circular flow across the whole volume
- you want to entrain oil bubbles into this flow
- you don't want to shear these bubbles into very small sizes, they should remain individually visible - in effect, you want to create the opposite of a fine emulsion

A process engineer designing a system to create a fine emulsion would choose a fast spinning impeller for high shear forces. So do the opposite:

- lower motor power until the droplet size increases to what you find visually appealing
- if there's no flow across the whole volume, increase impeller size - you may need to increase motor power with it, but generally large impellers are more efficient at creating large bulk flow - that may be up for experimenting
- It is entirely possible that at fluid speeds you like visually, the oil will form a stable layer on the water

Normally a vortex in a mixed vessel looks like in a kitchen mixer - *up*ward at the walls of the vessel, *in*ward at the surface of the fluid, *down*ward at the center of the vortex, *out*ward where the actuall mixer , the spinning part, is. Your vessel is so flat and the axis is horizontal so you won't achieve this three dimensional flow. Because your vessel is so flat it will likely be a more 2D flow.

Comment: Ok so you are saying creating vortex is not possible for my setup sadly.

Comment: But you did give me another idea! I will fill bottle with water till the height of motor and then the rest half with oil. Then using larger impeller with lower speed, I should be able to keep the bubbles without mixing into emulsion. By filling water and oil to half the height, oil will always be in contact with impeller too. Neat!

Answer (score 0):

The basics of the vortex are to generate varying velocity along the axis it rotates about and creating the drag effect, which involves the pressure differential. Due to the shallow depth of the bottle, I doubt the environment and geometry of the bottle meet the necessities for vorticity to occur, so, it seems unlikely.

Please read the linked articles that might provide useful clues.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex
https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/214/13/2283/10347/Characteristics-of-vortex-formation-and-thrust

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for, is called cavitation bubbles. Typically, this is a harmful phenomenon in the field of ship propeller screws. It is accompanied by vibration and noise, so likely you will not wish this will last long in your room. Visible cavitation will require more power and rotation speed than that motor gives, or smaller propeller. There are many articles and videos in the net about screw (propeller) cavitation.